# Encoded video's tempo is high in xuggler

Tags: java, xuggler

I am trying to convert mp4 to ts using IMediaWriter. Video encoded successfully but tempo is very high.

```
IContainer container = IContainer.make();
container.open(input, IContainer.Type.READ,null);
mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(container);
mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
mediaReader.addListener(new MediaListener());
for(int i=0; i< container.getNumStreams();i++){
    if(container.getStream(i).getStreamCoder().getCodecType() == Type.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO){
        FRAME_RATE = container.getStream(i).getFrameRate();

    }
    else if(container.getStream(i).getStreamCoder().getCodecType() == Type.CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO){
        sampleRate = container.getStream(i).getStreamCoder().getSampleRate();
    }
}
mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(output);
mediaWriter.addVideoStream(0, 0,
          FRAME_RATE,
          640,480);

startTime = System.nanoTime();
while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;
mediaWriter.close();
mediaReader.close();
```

## Listener

```
public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
    mediaWriter.encodeVideo(0,event.getImage(),System.nanoTime()-startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

}
```

**Note: I'm aware of this: `mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter)`. But I want to convert it manually like my code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem and writing the answer for future reference. Problem was the time stamp on video encoding. We need to read time stamp from `IVideoPictureEvent`.

```
public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
    mediaWriter.encodeVideo(0,event.getImage(),event.getTimeStamp(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS).longValue(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

}
```